# Load external resource only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to load a file (either jpg or pdf) into a popup as a preview. The extension of the file is not given in the URL.
The point is that as long as it is an image the file need to exactly fit into the popup and because of that I'd like to output an image tag with the external file. If its a pdf I'd like to output an iframe (we are requiring the browser to have a pdf-plugin).
To achieve this i wrote the following code in jQuery:

```
var src = "http://localhost/test/js/embed/test";
var popup = $("#popup");
var previewImage = $('<img style="width:100%" id="previewImage" />');
var previewFrame = $('<iframe id="previewFrame"></iframe >');

previewFrame.on("load", function() {
    //alert("frame loaded");
});
previewFrame.on("error", function() {
    //alert("frame error");
});
previewImage.on("load", function() {
    //alert("img loaded");
    popup.append(previewImage);
});
previewImage.on("error", function() {
    //alert("img error");
    previewFrame.attr("src", src);
    popup.append(previewFrame);
});
previewImage.attr("src", src);
```

Looking at the inspector i can see that, as long as a pdf is loaded, 2 requests are made for the file. Can I somehow change the code so that always only one request is made or are the 2 requests an issue anyway (will the second request take the file from the cache)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `2 requests are made for the file` one for the iframe? Or 2 without the iframe request?

Comment: Either 1 request for an image or 2 requests for a pdf file : I first try to load the resource as image. If success, show the image (1 request so far). If fails load the resource again but in the iframe (2 requests)